# C++ Object Retaining?

Tags: c++, object, retain

I'm an Objective-C programmer, and am recently starting C++, and I've stumbled into this question on my code's organization:

```
std::list<char *> stuff = std::list<char *>();
thing *object = new thing(stuff);
```

Where `stuff` would be an object that I'd need for the lifetime of my class (that is, until it gets destructed), how to avoid losing it?

On Objective-C, I could simply call `-retain` on the constructor. On C++?

Comment: If `stuff` is supposed to live exactly as long as `object` it maybe that it should be in object and just let RAII take care of its lifetime. Oh ps, `new anthing` is almost always evil so be careful

Comment: `thing` will not be destroyed until you explicitly `delete` it. I would recommend getting a good [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) to learn the basics.

Comment: how would you have `stuff` to fade out of existance? do you mean you're creating this inside a function?

Comment: If 'stuff' is scoped to a narrower scope than the intended lifetime of 'object', you'll have a dangling pointer unless your 'thing' class copies the string pointed to by 'stuff'.  Is overcoming that problem your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do not use pointers when you don't need them, and [don't use owning raw pointers](http://tinyurl.com/fuck-pointers) (unless you have a *very* good reason for them).

Use *automatic storage duration*:

```
std::list<char> stuff;
thing object{stuff};
```

The constructor of `thing` would take `std::list<char>` as its argument:

```
#include <utility> // for std::move

class thing {
public:
    explicit thing(std::list<char> stuff_) : stuff(std::move(stuff_)) {}

private:
    std::list<char> stuff;
};
```

If you do it this way, the destructor of `thing` will be called when `thing` goes out of scope, implicitly calling the destructor of `stuff`. Many [good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) explain this in great detail.

Unlike Objective-C, and C++ uses RAII rather than reference counting. The basic rule is: use automatic storage duration when possible, avoid raw owning pointers, and don't use `new` unless you have a good reason for it.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that this will only compile with a C++11 compiler, on GCC you'll need to use `g++ -std=c++0x`

Comment: Or if others needed access to the same list, to pass by reference and have the thing class take a reference to the list instead of moving it.  As is, there isn't a point to moving a newly constructed object.

Answer (score 1):

The usual way would be to copy or move `stuff` into `thing` in the constructor of `thing`:

```
class thing {
public:
    thing(std::list<char*> stuff) : stuff(std::move(stuff)) {}
private:
    std::list<char *> stuff;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how you are going to use `stuff` in your example, so I'm going to give you a few different options.

1. `thing` stores its own copy of `stuff`.
   In this case your class stores an object of type `std::list<char*>`.

   ```
   class thing
   {
   public:
     thing(std::list<char*>& aList):m_list(alist){}
     std::list<char*> m_list;
   };
   ```

   When you construct `thing` copy of `stuff` is made and stored in the class. When the object is destructed it will automatically deallocate `m_list`.
2. `thing` stores a weak reference to `stuff`.
   Your class will store a pointer (`std::list<char*>* m_list`) or reference (`std::list<char*>& m_list`). `thing` will be able to use your list in any way, but it shouldn't be in charge of resource management. If the list is in a smaller scope than `thing` then you'll be left with a hanging reference.

   ```
   thing getThing()
   {
   std::list<char*> list1;
   thing object1(list1);
   return object1; //bad - list will be deallocated, object1 will have a hanging reference
   }
   ```
3. `thing` stores a shared pointer to `stuff`.
   This is the method that is most like `retain` in Objective C. C++ doesn't have automatic reference counting. If you want to store an object reference with shared ownership you can use an `std::shared_ptr`. `thing` stores `std::shared_ptr<std::list<char*>> m_list`.

   ```
   std::shared_ptr<std::list<char*>> stuff = std::make_shared<std::list<char*>>();
   thing object(stuff); //reference count incremented, even if stuff is destroyed object will still hold a valid reference
   ```